# localhost is not working in IIS on virtual machine

Tags: iis, virtual-machine, iis-6

On my virtual machine with Windows 7, IIS 6.1 is installed. Everything was working up till January 2020 after that the websites stopped working. I tried checking localhost, it's not working either. I've checked all bindings and everything is correct. No ports are clashing. I've searched everywhere on the internet and tried all possible options but couldn't figure out why localhost is not working.
I'm getting the below error

[image]

I don't have much experience in virtual machines. Don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning IIS feature OFF, save and then ON worked for me. But still doesn't know why it happened in the first place.